Questions about groth16 paper "On the Size of Pairing-based Non-interactive Arguments"
i have many questions when reading groth16 paper "On the Size of Pairing-based Non-interactive Arguments" and the following are some of those. As the following graph shows.
1, What is "Perfect zero-knowledge"?
2, Does the following p1 same as p2?
3, What is the differences between
A(adversaries) and Verifiers?
4, What is the function of z(auxiliary
input z)
thanks.



The perfect hidding property of commitment scheme implies perfect ZK; 2. No, it is just  to demonstrate that no information/knowledge can be exposed, that's to say, without knowing the knowledge/witness, the simulator can generate a valid proof of statement $\phi$; 3. In the proof of ZK, the advesary plays the verifier of SNARK, the curious verifier who wants to learn knowledges; 4. The auxiliary input $z$ I guess is the input/output of circuit.

